# How does one subtract from concatenation in order to prove that $4\times 5 + 67 = 45 + 6\times 7$?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, conjectures

I noticed that if we get the numbers $4$, $5$, $6$ and $7$, they have an interesting property!

> $$4 \times 5 + 67 = 45 + 6 \times 7\tag*{= 87.}$$

I then conjectured that these were the only four consecutive positive integers with this property.

Hmm...

---

Let the four integers be $n$, $n+1$, $n+2$ and $n+3$. Then we have $$\begin{align} &n(n+1) + (n+2)\| (n+3) \\ =\;&n\| (n+1) + (n+2)(n+3).\tag{$\|\;\small{ \rm stands\;for}\;concatenation$}\end{align}$$ Or $$\begin{align} (n+2)\|(n+3)-n\|(n+1)&=(n+2)(n+3)-n(n+1) \\ &=n^2 + 5n + 6 - n^2 - n \\ &= 4n+ 6 \\ &= 2(2n+3).\end{align}$$

Now this is when I noticed that if $n=4$ then $2(2n+3)=22$. I may be able to reach $22$ like so:

> $$\begin{align}(n+2)\|(n+3)-n\|(n+1)&=(n+2-n)\|(n+3-n-1)\\ &=2\|2 \\ &= 22\end{align}$$

If that is true, then this happens: $$\begin{align}22 &= 2(2n+3)\\ \Leftrightarrow \; 11 &= 2n+3 \\ \Leftrightarrow \; \phantom{1}8 &= 2n \\ \\ \therefore \; n &= 4.\end{align}$$ This is my desired result, thus proving the conjecture. But is the equation in the second sandbox true?

> > ***How does one subtract from concatenation?***

This, in particular, is new to me; I would mostly appreciate a full, explanatory answer.

---

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $n = 8$, then $1011-89 = 922 \neq 22$. Similarly, if $n = 10$, then $1213-1011 = 202$.

Comment: @Ennar Ok... but where would (strictly) knowing this lead unprovided the answer below?

Comment: $a||b = 10^ka+b$, where $k$ is the number of digits of $b$, so you should consider different cases. Also, $n,n+1,n+2,n+3$ don't need to have the same number of digits.

Comment: @Ennar well, *before* proving that $n=4$, yes, we can assume that $n,\ldots, n+3$ do not need to have the same digits. Also, there are infinitely many cases to consider because for $n\in \mathbb{Z}_+$ there are infinitely many values of $n$ to choose from; i.e. *infinitely* many cases. So I reckon the answer provided below is much more efficient and additionally elegant, no disrespect.

Comment: Also happens to be incorrect for general $n$, as my counterexamples show.

Comment: @Ennar How is it a counter-example? $n=8$ and $n=10$ are not counter-examples, if you are referring to them. We are looking for a given $n$ such that $(n+2)\| (n+3) - n\| (n+1) = 22$, not $n$ itself. Only $n=4$ satisfies this equation. We can *let* $n$ be any positive integer and then come to the conclusion that it can't be, simply by manipulating equations. Am I mistaken?

Comment: I thought you wanted to prove it in general, not solve equation. In that case, $n = 0, 1, \ldots, 6$ are also solutions, not only $n = 4$.

Comment: @Ennar $0\times 1 + 23 \neq 01 + 2\times 3$ and $1\times 2+ 34 \neq 12 + 3\times 4$ and $2\times 3 + 45 \neq 23 + 4\times 5$ and etc. These are counterexamples to the solutions $n\in\{0,1,2\}$. As proven, $n=4$ *is* the only solution, but I will work on rephrasing my question better for your comprehension.

Comment: I am talking about $(n+2)||(n+3)-n||(n+1) = 22$, since you wrote "But is the equation in the second sandbox, true?". The answer is not in general, but not only for $n = 4$.

Comment: @Ennar But... how? The answer below proves it... right? :\

Comment: Well I explained couple of comments ago that it doesn't and gave you an idea how to work it out.

Comment: But $$\begin{align} (n+2)\|(n+3)-n\|(n+1)&=10(n+2)+(n+3)-10(n)-(n+1)\tag{given} \\ &=10n+20+n+3-10n-n-1\\ &=20+3-1 \\ &=22.\end{align}$$ But... the counter-examples? Where did the algebra go wrong???

Comment: @Ennar oh wait... $a\| b = 10^\color{red}{k}a + b$. So that means in the comment above, we assume $b$ only has one digit... but that means we don't let $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ do we, but actually we falsely let $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\setminus \mathbb{Z}_{>9}$. Uh oh...

Comment: Yes. I have to leave now and can take a look at your problem later. Another solution to your initial problem: $49\cdot 50 + 5152 =  4950 + 51\cdot 52$. Also, $n = 10^k/2 - 1$ is a solution for any positive integer $k$.

Comment: @Ennar !!! ${}{}$

Comment: **Generalisation:** Let $i,j,k,m$ be positive integers such that $m,m+i+j\in(10^k,10^{k+1})$. Then we wish to solve the generalised equation $$m(m+1)\cdots(m+i)+(m+i+1)\|(m+i+2)\|\cdots\|(m+i+j)\\=\\m\|(m+1)\|\cdots\|(m+i)+(m+i+1)(m+i+2)\cdots(m+i+j)$$ which can be written as $$\frac{(m+i+j)!}{(m+i)!}-\frac{(m+i)!}{m!}=\sum_{r=1}^j(m+i+r)\cdot10^{k(j-r)}-\sum_{s=0}^i(m+s)\cdot10^{k(i+1-s)}.$$ Given $i,j$, it is possible to find $m$, though not necessarily analytically.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to consider also bases other than ten.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire what does it mean to find $m$ *analytically*? I guess that is a generalised equation, but I don't know how to proceed from it... :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have the following cases:

- $n+1,n+3$ both have $k\ge1$ digits; then$$(n+2)||(n+3)-n||(n+1)=10^k(n+2)+(n+3)-10^k(n)-(n+1)\\=2(1+10^k)$$For solutions to your problem in this case,$$2n+3=1+10^k$$You can get infinitely many solutions $\{4,49,499,4999,...\}=\{10^k/2-1:k\in\Bbb N\}$ using different $k$, meaning that the solution is **not unique**.
- $n+3$ has $k+1$ digits and $n+1$ has $k\ge1$ digits; then $$(n+2)||(n+3)-n||(n+1)=10^{k+1}(n+2)+(n+3)-10^k(n)-(n+1)\\=2+10^k(9n+20)$$The solutions are given by$$2n+3=1+10^{k-1}(45n+100)$$Note that $10^{k-1}(45n+100)\ge45n+100>2n+3$, so there is no solution in this case.

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot I could write it like that: I was so focused on the digits of concatenation that I wasn't concerned with the algebraic *expression* it obeyed! I suppose I only needed a hint, but this answer definitely suffices for a $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ nevertheless! Thank you, and well done! $(+1)$ :D

Comment: @user477343 Even without expanding it out like that, recall how we manually carry out subtraction: we write the numbers one below the other and subtract corresponding digits, as you have shown.

Comment: Actually, uhh... you might want to look at @Ennar's comments under my question. They, well, take away the opportunity of your answer receiving a tick, thus far :{

Comment: @user477343 Thanks for pointing that out. I was oddly under the assumption that $n$ is a single digit number. I should have read the question carefully. Anyway, here you go!